# Does maven-shade-plugin allow for packed dependency jars to be included?

Tags: maven

maven-shade-plugin includes the dependencies unpacked within the uber jar, which makes sense because of the shading that is involved.

Is there a way to allow for a specific 'safe' dependency to be included as a whole jar (not unpacked into classes)? I could not see such a thing in the docs.

Comment: Why you need this?

Comment: @Jens adding the jar in a PaaS env, which then checks the existence of that jar within the app (otherwise it tries to attach its own version as a dependency)